# C# Finding Maximum Value of Items that fit in certain slots

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, knapsack-problem

All,

I'm having an issue wrapping my head around how to find the ideal relationship between 2 values while also having to fit those items into a certain position.  I honestly don't even know where to begin.  I researched the knapsack problem, but there is no positional requirements.

Example:

I have $50.00 to spend on food.  I need to eat 4 meals (breakfast, lunch, dinner, and a snack - which can be breakfast or lunch).  Each meal has 4? properties; name, slot, calories, and cost.  My goal is to eat the most calories while staying under my $50.00 allotment.

```
class Meal
{
    public enum MealType
    {
        Breakfast = 1,
        Lunch = 2,
        Dinner = 3
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MealType Type { get; set; }
    public int Calories { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public Meal(string _name, MealType _type, int _calories, decimal _cost)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Type = _type;
        Calories = _calories;
        Cost = _cost;
    }
}
```

I'm able to read in from a spreadsheet or some other source and create a Meal for each record and add it to a List.  I have no idea how to read through my list (or any collection), though, and find the maximum caloric combination of 4 meals while adhering to the requirement that Meal #1 must be of type "breakfast", Meal #2 must be of type "lunch", Meal #3 must be of type "dinner", and Meal #4 can be of type "breakfast" or "lunch".  Any ideas on where to begin?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I ended up getting this to work - though I'm sure it is not very efficient, especially as the input list grows.  Here is the hideous code (I obviously also defined a Menu class not included):

```
        List<Meal> allMeals = Meal.GetMeals();
        List<Meal> allBreakfast = new List<Meal>();
        List<Meal> allLunch = new List<Meal>();
        List<Meal> allDinner = new List<Meal>();
        List<Meal> allSnack = new List<Meal>();

        foreach (Meal meal in allMeals)
        {
            if (meal.MealType == Meal.MealType.Breakfast)
            {
                allBreakfast.Add(meal);
                allSnack.Add(meal);
            }
            else if (meal.MealType == Meal.MealType.Lunch)
            {
                allLunch.Add(meal);
                allSnack.Add(meal);
            }
            else if (meal.MealType == Meal.MealType.Dinner)
            {
                allDinner.Add(meal);
            }
        }

        foreach (Meal breakfast in allBreakfast)
        {
            foreach (Meal lunch in allLunch)
            {
                foreach (Meal dinner in allDinner)
                {
                    foreach (Meal snack in allSnack)
                    {
                        if (snack == breakfast || snack == lunch)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        currMenu = new Menu(breakfast, lunch, dinner, snack);

                        if (currMenu.Cost < Menu.MaxCost && (maxMenu == null || currMenu.Calories > maxMenu.Calories))
                        {
                            maxMenu = currMenu;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might try transforming into a network flow problem, and using Ford–Fulkerson algorithm or similar to compute a solution.

Comment: Look like a Knapsack problem to me, which can solve by using dynamic programming

Comment: Look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, if you are not familiar with complex algorithm, you can try the brute force algo which is still feasible in the time and memory space.

We have 4 sets to store record: A, B, C, D (A: breakfast, B: lunch, C: dinner, D = A + B)

Our aim is to find Ai, Bj, Cu, Dv so as to:

```
1. Ai.cost + Bj.cost + Cu.cost + Dv.cost <=50 
2. Ai.calo + Bj.calo + Cu.calo + Dv.calo is maximum
```

As in reality, we just count up to 2 decimal--> range of price is from 0.00 -> 50.00, i.e. 5000 case

```
1. Find all cost combination of Ai + Bj (<=50) store into array AB.
     if (Ai1  + Bj1 == Ai2 + Bj2), just take combination have higher calories.
=> Complexity: O(|A| * |B|)


2. Find all cost combination of Cu + Dv (<=50) store into array CD with the same process as for AB
=> Complexity: O(|C| * |D|)
Note: size of AB and CD is 5000 elements

3. Find all combination AB[p] + CD[q] which cost is under 5000 and we can know which one got highest calories.
=> Complexity: O(|AB| * |CD| ) = O(5000 * 5000)
```

Totally, if using brute-force, the time complexity is O(5000 * 5000) + O(|spreadSheet size for one categories|^2).

If the spreadSheet size is <= 5000 and you are not familiar with algorithm, you can use this simple approach. Otherwise, just move ahead, algorithm is fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you have read about Knapsack problem, and still don't know how to solve it, here is something for you to consider

The idea is simple, the array **result** contains all the value of money that can be reached by any Meal combination. So at first, when you doesn't buy anything, only result[50] can be reached.

Iterating through all the choices, starting from **breakfast to snack**, and **only** check for the **value that can be reached**, we can slowly build up the value table. For example, if breakfast has three prices(1,2,3) so the next state can only be (50-1), (50-2), (50-3) and so on. In array result, we store the maximum value of calories which can be created. So if one Breakfast set is cost 3, calo 2, and another set is cost 3, calo 4, so the value at index (50 -3) of the result array is 4.

Finally, after scanning through all of the state, the value storing in result array is the maximum value of calories that can be made.

```
            int money = 50;// your initial money
            int[] result = new int[money + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                result[i] = -1;//-1 means cannot reach
            }
            result[50] = 0;//Only 50 can be reached at first
            List<Meal>[] list = new List[4]; // Array for all 4 meals
                                             // 0 is Breakfast
                                             // 1 is lunch
                                             // 2 for dinner
                                             // 3 for snack

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//Iterating from breakfast to snack
                int[] temp = new int[money + 1];//A temporary array to store value
                for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    temp[j] = -1;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    if (result[j] != -1) {//For previous value, which can be reached
                                          //Try all posibilites
                        for (int k = 0; k < list[i].size(); k++) {
                            int cost = list[i].get(k).cost;
                            int energy = list[i].get(k).energy;
                            if (cost <= result[j]) {
                                temp[j - cost] = max(temp[j - cost], result[j] + energy);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                result = temp;//Need to switch these arrays.
            }
            int max = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                max = max(max, result[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: I'm missing something.  This never does any work, because when you try to iterate through each list:
    for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    if (result[j] != -1) {//For previous value, which can be reached
                                          //Try all posibilites  
This always evaluates to false except at result[50].

Comment: @user1695263 look at line result = temp, so at the end, I update the result array with the content in the temp array.